# How do I make the mapper process the entire file from HDFS

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hapi

This is the code where I read the file that contain Hl7 messages and iterate through them using Hapi Iterator (from http://hl7api.sourceforge.net)

```
File file = new File("/home/training/Documents/msgs.txt");
InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);
is = new BufferedInputStream(is);

Hl7InputStreamMessageStringIterator iter = new   
     Hl7InputStreamMessageStringIterator(is);
```

I want to make this done inside the map function? obviously I need to prevent the splitting in *InputFormat* to read the entire file as once as a single value and change it toString (the file size is 7KB), because as you know Hapi can parse only entire message.

I am newbie to all of this so please bear with me.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to implement you own [FileInputFormat](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.6.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/FileInputFormat.html) subclass:

1. It must override `isSplittable()` method to `false` which means that number of mappers will be equal to number of input files: one input file per each mapper.
2. You also need to implement `getRecordReader()` method. This is exactly the class where you need to put you parsing logic from above to.

Comment: thank you for replying, please can you refer me to samples and example for the code

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want your data file to split or you want a single mapper which will process your entire file. So that one file will be processed by only one mapper. In that case extending map/reduce inputformat and overriding isSplitable() method and return "false" as boolean will help you.

For ref : ( Not based on your code )
https://gist.github.com/sritchie/808035

Comment: thank you for the ref, i added the code there but still the same error :( should i change the <k, v> in the inputformat the same that i have with <text, text> ?

Answer (score 0):

As the input is getting from the text file, you can override isSplitable() method of fileInputFormat. Using this, one mapper will process the whole file.

`public boolean isSplitable(Context context,Path args[0])
{
   return false;
}`